# Android lint: Unbound xml namespace prefix. Only for resources of other build variants

Tags: android, xml, namespaces, resources, lint

My Android project consists of 4 build variants: 2 product flavors and 2 build types. All of these have got their own resources files, like this:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
    <string name="app_title">MyApp</string>
</resources>
```

When I run android lint it shows the warning 'Unbound XML namespace prefix', due to the Android tools I use to ignore 'MissingTranslation'. However, this warning is shown for all files except the buildVariant I've currently selected. When I switch buildVariant the error for the file used for that buildVariant disappears.

So I guess the namespace cannot be found for different build variants, so I can probably ignore this warning. Am I correct?
If so: is there a way to suppress these warnings?
If not: what should I do to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I've found out this doesn't happen only to files with `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"`, but also with simple files like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="description_logo_of_app">Logo of MyApp</string>
</resources>
```

Also, this happens to a single file per product flavor / build type only, apparently only strings files (not sure if it is a coincidence, or just the first file lint checks).

My workaround now is suppressing the warning with `<!--suppress XmlUnboundNsPrefix -->` above the `<resources>` tag, but I don't like it. Better solutions still welcome!

Comment: Same issue. I have 3 flavors (normal, beta, free) and lint show the same warning as you for strings.xml of beta and free flavors, as also for the google_maps_api.xml I use to place a google maps credential for release version.